# OpenShift, casperjs command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, phantomjs, openshift, casperjs

I have these dependencies specified in my package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "casperjs": "*",
    "phantomjs": "*"
},
```

When I push these onto the OpenShift server, I cannot use their commands like `casperjs test.js`. I get a `bash: casperjs: command not found`. However, I do see casperjs and phantomjs folders in the node_modules.

If I manually do an `npm install casperjs` in the repo folder, the command will work. I thought once I push changes to OpenShift, the builder will automatically do the npm installs for the dependencies I specified. What am I missing here?

Update: Since phantomjs is a dependency as well, I tried what was suggested here
https://blog.openshift.com/screen-scraper-as-a-service/
I installed the binary and the command `phantomjs` works. But when I restart my OpenShift server, the command no longer works. Do I need to add commands

`cd app-root/data/
    wget http://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.8.0-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
    tar xf phantomjs-1.8.0-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
    rm phantomjs-1.8.0-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
    mv phantomjs-1.8.0-linux-x86_64/ phantomjs`

to the scripts.start in package.json? I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: You probably need to install it globally.

Comment: It looks like OpenShift doesn't allow global installs.

Comment: I  uploaded Phantomjs and caperjs manually to the data directory.

Comment: How did you add it there? I used the phantomjs binary and unpacked the files in /data. The `phantomjs` command worked until I restarted my server. Do I need to run a binary install each time my server restarts?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new application and installed casperjs and phantomjs through npm. Now each of their commands will work after restarting the server. I assume the problem I has having was a bug or something misconfigured I couldn't spot.